# How to hover a Fixed element until it reaches some point

Tags: jquery, css, css-position

I've got a div which I need to be fixed to the bottom of the screen, until it reaches some point after scrolling and stop there and stay. If a user start scrolling back up - make it fixed again after passing that same point.

Any ideas on how this can be accomplished?

EDIT: (here's my current code which doesn't work)

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() < $(document).height() - 81) {
        $('#bottom_pic').css('bottom', "0px");
    }
    else {
        $('#bottom_pic').css('bottom', "81px");
    }
});
```

CSS:

```
#bottom_pic 
{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: @roman we can easily do that kind of stuff, but can you explain even more clear..if possible

Comment: @gov - sure. I have a div element which has position:fixed and bottom: 0px; which means it's just fixed to the bottom. I wish it to stop being fixed when it reaches 80px from the bottom (after I scroll down) and get back to be being fixed when I again scroll back up. Hope it's better explained now.

Comment: @roman can you please edit the code by 101010 symbol or cntr-k

Comment: sorry - didn't know about the cntr-k thingy :) thanks

Comment: May I point you to a tutorial for something similar, at [jQuery For Designers](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/fixed-floating-elements/), with a [demo available there](http://static.jqueryfordesigners.com/demo/fixedfloat.html).

Comment: @David - thank you. I'll go over it now. Seems it might help :)

Comment: @roman see the viewsoure on the demo link provided by david , it has all the code// its exactly what you are looking for

Comment: @roman, has this issue been solved, yet?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[jQuery Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.github.com/jquery-waypoints/) is an excellent plugin to achieve things like this: [Demo of fixed div after scrolling](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/shortcuts/sticky-elements/)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with a site. I had a div container that had two columns. A right column that contained long text based articles. In the left column was a div navigation list that contained anchor links to each text article in the right column. I wanted the navigation to scroll with the page. However, it shouldn't go above the texts, or below them. I wrote the following function for it:

```
HTML:
<div id="texts-container">
     <div id="texts">Right column of long texts</div>
     <div id="texts-sidebar">Left Column navigation that scrolls with page</div>
</div>

JS Function:
function shift_text_nav() {
     var top = $(window).scrollTop();
     var t = $('#texts-container').offset().top;
     var left = $('#texts-container').offset().left;
     if (top > (t)) {
          var text_height = $('#texts').height();
          var nav_height = $('#texts-sidebar').height();

          if(t + text_height - nav_height  - 40< top){
               $('#texts-sidebar').css({'position':'absolute','top': (text_height - nav_height) + 'px','left':'0px'});
          }else{
               $('#texts-sidebar').css({'position':'fixed','top':'40px','left':left+'px'});
          }
     } else {
          $('#texts-sidebar').css({'position':'absolute','top':'40px','left':'0px'});
     }
}

$(window).scroll(function() { shift_text_nav(); });
$(window).resize(function() { shift_text_nav(); });
shift_text_nav();
```

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is an old topic... however I needed to implement something of this nature recently. Below is the code to accomplish the task (keep in mind you may need to modify the css to get it to show in the appropriate location for your needs, mine was to dock the element at the top of the screen). Additionally, this is dependent on jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //  initialize the dock
    Dock();

    // add the scroll event listener
    if (window.addEventListener) {
        window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll, false);
    } else {
        window.attachEvent('onscroll', handleScroll);
    }
});

function Dock() {
    Dock.GetDock = document.getElementById('dockable');
    Dock.NewScrollOffset = getScrollOffset();
    Dock.DockBottomPos = getDockBottomPos();
    Dock.DockTopPos = getDockTopPos();
}

function getScrollOffset() {
    var scrollOffset = window.pageYOffset
                ? window.pageYOffset
                : document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    return scrollOffset;
}

function getDockBottomPos() {
    var dockTopPos = getDockTopPos();
    var dockHeight = $('#dockable').height();
    return (dockTopPos + dockHeight);
}

function getDockTopPos() {
    var dockTopPos = $('#dockable').offset().top;
    return dockTopPos;
}

function handleScroll(){
     if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {

          //  determine the distance scrolled from top of the page
          Dock.NewScrollOffset = getScrollOffset();

          if (Dock.NewScrollOffset >= Dock.DockBottomPos) {
              Dock.GetDock.className = "fixed";
              return;
          }
          if (Dock.NewScrollOffset <= Dock.DockTopPos) {
              Dock.GetDock.className = "";
          }
      }
 }
```

css:

```
#dockable
{
    position: relative;
    width: inherit;
}
#dockable.fixed
{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
}
```

An example of a dock would be...

```
#dockable div
{
    display: inline;
    *zoom: 1;
    height: 25px;
    line-height: 25px;
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
}
<div id="dockable">
     <div><a href="#">Menu Item 1</div>
     <div><a href="#">Menu Item 2</div>
     <div><a href="#">Menu Item 3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    checkPosition('#myelement');
});

function checkPosition( element ){
//choose your limit
var positionLimit = 416;
var y = getOffsetY();

if( y <= positionLimit ){
    $(element).css({'position':'fixed','bottom':'0'});
}
else{
    $(element).css({'position':'relative'});
}
}
```

//for browser compatibility

```
function getOffsetY(){

var  scrOfY = 0;
    if( typeof( window.pageYOffset ) == 'number' ) {
        //Netscape compliant
        scrOfY = window.pageYOffset;
    } else if( document.body && ( document.body.scrollTop ) ) {
        //DOM compliant
        scrOfY = document.body.scrollTop;
    } else if( document.documentElement && (  document.documentElement.scrollTop ) ) {
        //IE6 standards compliant mode
        scrOfY = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    }

return scrOfY;
}
```

This should be work. To get y offset of the element you'd have to use a function in order to have browser compatibility. All you have to do is set the correct limit position.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to go about it:

- either go with an absolute pos, and compensate for every scrollbar movement *below* a certain level
- or go with a fixed pos, and compensate *above* a certain level.

In both case, what you need is "*a linear curve with a dent*" regarding "position value over scroll value". The best to achieve this are the Math.min/max functions. Hint: The *fixed* approach is less *wobbly* for the standstill-part. Unless you need IE6 support (which knows no fixed), go with the #fix solution.

```
<style type="text/css">
body { 
    height:1000px;  /* create something to scroll*/
    border-left: 20px dotted blue; /* and something fancy */
}

#abs { position:absolute; top: 200px; left:100px; background-color:#FCC; }
#fix { position:fixed;    top: 200px; left:200px; background-color:#CCF; }      
</style>

<div id="abs">Absolute</div>          <div id="fix">Fixed</div>

<script type="text/javascript"> <!-- have jQuery included before -->
    $(window).scroll( function () {
        $('#abs').css('top', 200 + Math.min( 150, $(window).scrollTop() ));
        /* read: up to 150, compensate scrolling,
                    then stick with a fixed value (scroll along) */

        $('#fix').css('top', 200 - Math.max( 0 , $(window).scrollTop() - 150 )); 
        /* read: do nothing in the interval [0;150] */
    });         
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  if($(this).scrollTop() < $(document).height() -1000){
    $(selector).css("position", "fixed");
    $(selector).css("bottom","0");
  }
  else
  {
    $(selector).css('bottom', "81px");
  }
});
```

I tried this code and it works for $(document).height() -500 ). But for some reason i can't understand it does not work when the value 500 is decreased to 100 or 81.

Try changing this value and see the difference

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for resurrecting the "dead", but I came across this question with the same question and thought I'd share the solution I came up with. In my case, I have images (`#rm_gutter_left and #rm_gutter_right`) on either side of a center aligned fix width site and a fluid width header and footer. You could adjust it to only be for one element or use a class, of course.

Hope this helps someone else.

```
// Height and footer settings
var rm_header_height = 67; // px
var rm_footer_height = 200; // px

// Store so jquery only has to find them once
var rm_gutters = $("#rm_gutter_left, #rm_gutter_right");

// Set initial gutter position
rm_gutters.css("top", rm_header_height + "px");

// Attach to window's scroll event
$(window).scroll(function() {
    st = $(this).scrollTop();
    h = $(document).height() - $(window).height();

    // Is the header still in view?
    if (st < rm_header_height) {
        rm_gutters.css({"top": rm_header_height + "px", "bottom": "auto"});

    // Are neither the footer or header in view?
    } else if (st < h - rm_footer_height) {
        rm_gutters.css({"top": 0, "bottom": "auto"});

    // Is the footer in view?
    } else {
        rm_gutters.css({"top": "auto", "bottom": rm_footer_height + "px"});
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() < $(document).height() - 81) {
        $('#bottom_pic').css("position", "fixed");
        $('#bottom_pic').css('bottom', "0px");
    }
    else {
        $('#bottom_pic').css("position", "absolute");
        $('#bottom_pic').css({'top':(($(document).height())-81)+'px'});
    }
});
```

This will make the div fixed at bottom until its 81px away from the top. Once it reaches there, it will stay there.

Answer (score -2):

```
*@roman , the below function triggers the scroll event* ,
```

you can place all your custom logic inside this/// calculating , positioning etc

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    /* this function gets triggered whenever you do scroll.
       Write all your logic inside this */
});
```

Comment: that's exactly what I'm trying to do with no success. What logic should be there? (I'll write what I've been trying to do)

Comment: @roman define this event in your code and do a lert inside and let me know if it is firing , then we can work on your logic to get it done.