# Make fixed position div stay where it is when scroll position is at bottom

Tags: jquery, css

I have a fixed position div that sits at `bottom:0`. When I scroll down to `$('html').height()-200`, I want my fixed position `div` to be `position: absolute; top: $('html').height)-200`.

Any ideas on how to make this work?

I got pretty close but the code is wonky if your browser window is too tall.

The problem in my code lies in

```
    $('html,body').height()-800;
```

Here is an example. Note your browser needs to be a certain size for it to work. The "800" integer in the jsFiddle example is an arbitrary number and that part of the code is what I don't know how to fix.

http://jsfiddle.net/HVhLw/11/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to hover a Fixed element until it reaches some point](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4372246/how-to-hover-a-fixed-element-until-it-reaches-some-point)

Comment: I deleted my answer. I still don't get your problem. ;)

Comment: I posted a jsFiddle example and Tom's duplicate post is the same problem I have.

Comment: Thank you for the meaningless downvote because you did not understand my question.

Comment: @Chris: If people don't understand it, perhaps you didn't explain it properly.

Comment: If you solved your problem, write an answer.

Comment: You have to wait when you don't have 30k reputation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself, thank you for those who helped. When you want to make a fixed: position div stay where it is after scrolling a certain amount, your scrollTop() condition should be:

```
($(document).height()-$(window).height())-200
```

$(document).height() is the height of the page

$(window).height() is the height of the viewport

200 is how far from the bottom of the viewport you want your div to 'stick' to

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('html,body').height($('html,body').height()-1050);
```

instead of

```
$('html,body').height()-1050;
```

Comment: It's the 1050 part that is wrong. I"m not sure what will make it work, though. It's an arbitrary number that only works when the browser is a certain size.

Answer (score 0):

Use [jQuery waypoints](http://imakewebthings.github.com/jquery-waypoints/) to change the positioning behaviour of the `div` when required.

Comment: I appreciate this answer and I'm sure it would solve my problem but I'd like to learn how to do this without using a third party library.

Comment: Yeah, if you want to be pedantic. You know what I meant.

Comment: @Chris: No.. I don't. You don't want to use third party libraries, but you're using one. That's not me being pedantic; that's me being very confused.

Comment: I'd like to learn how to do it without using a jquery plugin? Make it work my way to understand how viewport calculation works and how to detect scroll position from bottom? I enjoy learning, not simply using someone elses code for a learning exercise.